# Javascript: Cancelling prompt via another function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I have prompt loop, but I want to have the loop cancelled when I click on a div button on the page. What kind of function do I have to write to cancel the loop?

```
function askName(){
    var strName = prompt("What is your name?");
        if (!strName){
            askName();
        } else {
            document.writeln("<h1>" 
            + strName + "</h1>");
            askDate();
        }
 }
```

And i have the html page

```
<div id ="cancelling" onClick="function_cancel">
    Cancel
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do that with native `prompt`.

Comment: `prompt` is synchronous, it blocks everything until the user answers. Why don't you use an `<input>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with the element on page, however you can properly handle the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button click like that:

```
function askName() {
    var strName = prompt("What is your name?");        
    if (strName == null) { //cancel button clicked, dont ask anymore
        return;
    }
    if (strName === "") { //empty name, ask again
        askName();        
    } else {
        //document.writeln("<h1>" + strName + "</h1>");
        //do not use document.write!
        var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        h1.innerHTML = strName;
        document.body.appendChild(h1);
        askDate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nature of JavaScript in browsers is single threaded. That means that until you answer the prompt no other code can execute. Events can still be dispatched and added to the event queue (ex: incoming XHR responses), but they will not be handled until the current execution context  is over (the functions end).

In other words, there is no function that can run while the prompt is active, so there's no way to write it.